# mgo ony the last JSON entry

Tags: go, mgo

I used the code below to store JSON entry in MongoDB, but only the last entry "c2" is stored. What did I do wrong?

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "labix.org/v2/mgo"
    "labix.org/v2/mgo/bson"
)

func insertEntry(j *map[string]interface{}, entry string) {
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(entry), &j)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

}

func main() {
    c1 := `{
    "mw" : 42.0922,
    "ΔfH°gas" : {
      "value" : 372.38,
      "units" : "kJ/mol"
    },
    "S°gas" : {
      "value" : 216.81,
      "units" : "J/mol×K"
    },
    "index" : [
      {"name" : "mw", "value" : 42.0922},
      {"name" : "ΔfH°gas", "value" : 372.38},
      {"name" : "S°gas", "value" : 216.81}
    ]
    }`

    c2 := `{
    "name": "silicon",
    "mw": 32.1173,
    "index": [
      {
    "name": "mw",
    "value": 32.1173
      }
    ]
    }`

    m := make(map[string]interface{})

    insertEntry(&m, c1)
    insertEntry(&m, c2)
    chemical := m["ΔfH°gas"].(map[string]interface{})
    fmt.Println("value: ", chemical["value"].(float64))
    fmt.Println("units: ", chemical["units"].(string))

    session, err := mgo.Dial("localhost")

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer session.Close()

    // Optional. Switch the session to a monotonic behavior.
    session.SetMode(mgo.Monotonic, true)

    c := session.DB("test").C("chemicals")
    err = c.Insert(&m)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    result := &m
    err = c.Find(bson.M{"name": "silicon"}).One(&m)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(result)
    fmt.Println("mw:", m["mw"])

    fmt.Println("value: ", chemical["value"].(float64))
    fmt.Println("units: ", chemical["units"].(string))

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is the way you're building up your map. Your call to json.Unmarshall is taking all of the "top-level" entries in your json and making them keys in your map. In this case, those would be `mw`, `ΔfH°gas`, `S°gas`, `index`, `name`, `mw`, and `index`.

Note that `mw` and `index` are repeated across `c1` and `c2`. That means when you call `insertEntry(c2)`, you're overwriting the `mw` and `index` entries. If you print out the contents of your map after each call to `insertEntry` you can observe this behavior.

There are a few things you could do to avoid this, depending on your needs. You could reformat your json to avoid these conflicts, you could call `c.Insert` once for each of your `c` variables (with a fresh map for each one) which would result in different mongodb documents being created for each json chemical definition instead of one big one containing both.

Comment: I tried to call c.Insert once for each of c variables with this [code](https://github.com/mictadlo/mgo/blob/master/chemeo/chemeo.go), but now I got the following errors: "./chemeo.go:11: cannot convert entry (type []string) to type []byte
./chemeo.go:51: cannot use chemicals (type map[string]interface {}) as type *map[string]interface {} in function argument". How is it possible to fix them?